# Pass object to component - vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I've tried a few different things and now must ask for some help (thanks in advance).

I'm creating a simple Vue js app where a component form emits data as a object (this works) to its parent.
the parent then runs a v-for loop and passes the Object data to a component which displays the data (this does not work).

Vue Version

```
($ vue --version
@vue/cli 4.4.1)
```

Parent code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="MEDS">
    <goalForm @goal_data="goal_create($event)"/>
    <section>
      <div v-for="(goalItem, index) in this.goals_list_container" v-bind:key="index">
        <goalItem :goal="goalItem"/>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
// @ is an alias to /src
import goalForm from '@/components/Goal_form.vue'
import goalItem from '@/components/Goal_item.vue'

export default {
  name: 'MEDS',
  components: {
    goalForm,
    goalItem

  },
  data(){
    return{
      // Recievs goals from goalForm on submit, this is an array of objects
      goals_list_container: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    goal_create(payload){
      this.goals_list_container.push(payload);
      console.log(this.goals_list_container)
    }
  }
}
```

GOAL ITEM (that should display the goal)

```html
<template>
 <div>
      <h3>{{goal.title}}</h3>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
 prop: ['goal'],
 data(){
   return {
     goal: {}
   }
 },
 watch: {
  
 }
}
```

Goal_form: (EDITED)

```
 <div>
    <form action="" class="goalForm" @submit.prevent="emit_Goal">
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" v-model="title">
      <input type="text" name="description" id="description" v-model="des">
      <input type="date" name="dueDate" id="dueDate" v-model="dueDate">
      <input type="number" name="priority" id="priority" v-model="priority">
      <input type="submit" class="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
          title: null,
          des: null,
          dueDate: null,
          priority: null,
          goal_data: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    push_goal(){
      this.goal_data.title = this.title
      this.goal_data.des = this.des
      this.goal_data.dueDate = this.dueDate
      this.goal_data.priority = this.priority
    },
    emit_Goal(){
      // Move goal details into Object to be Emited
      this.push_goal()
      // Emit the form to the parent on submit
      this.$emit('goal_data', this.goal_data)
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    input {
      &[name="title"]{
        
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```

The for loop seems to work as each submit of the Goal_form creates a new instance of the Goal_item component.... But it does not populate with any data.

[image]

I Am either getting this totally wrong or have missed something small but any help would be greatly appreciated -

W

Comment: FYI, custom event names should be kebab-cased. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

Comment: Oh, I think I see what's wrong. You are overwriting your `goal` prop in `goalItem` with an empty object in the `data` function. Remove the `data` property

Comment: Hi Phil -  Thank you so much for your input, I have added the Goal_form template (sorry for missing that out)

Comment: @Phil I added the data goal to the Goal_item template as without I recieved an error: "Property or method "goal" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property."

Comment: You really have to stop re-using names. In your `v-for` loop, you're overwriting the `goalItem` component reference with the `goalItem` iteration variable. I suggest you have a good long read of the [Vue style guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/). Personally, I would use `GoalItem` for the component name and `v-for="(goal, index) in goals_list_container"`

Comment: Also, it's `props` not `prop` (that's your problem)

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out (prop not props) and also linking the styles guide. Your help was greatly appreciated (I just wish it wasn't because of such a small mistake)

Comment: It's almost always a _small mistake_ 

Comment: @Phil Post it as an answer to mark it as answered and avoid new people looking at this question ;)

Comment: @Kapcash I've already voted to close this as a _typo_